# Using pivot on pandas introduces unwanted NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, data-wrangling

I'm doing some basic data wrangling and counting the number of True's and False's that each version has in the data below.

Here's my pandas dataframe (df):

```
    version  type    count
0   A        False   80
1   A        True    11
2   B        False   72
3   B        True    53
```

I'm attempting to `pivot` my dataframe using:

```
DF = df.pivot(values='count',columns='type')
```

But I get a bunch of NaNs between my rows: (current output)

```
type  False  True
0     80     NaN
1     NaN    11
2     72     NaN
3     NaN    53
```

Here's my desired output:

```
False  True
80     11
72     53
```

For context, I will then take the proportion of True/False after summing the two columns.

I know this is pretty simple, but am new to python and online solutions haven't quite given me solutions to this basic reshaping. Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.pivot(values='count',columns='type', index = 'version').reset_index(drop = True)
```

You need to specify `index`.

result:

```
type  False  True 
0        80     11
1        72     53
```